# Magnetic anomaly explanation

Tags: electromagnetism

Two magnets with like poles facing one another repel. if a piece of ferromagnetic material is added to one, both magnets are attracted to it, thus overcoming the repelling force. However, if a similar piece of ferromagnetic material is added to the "like" pole of the second magnet, the two again repel. How can this phenomenon best be explained?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming mass and surface area play an important role in the answer. My guess is, so long as the mass of the ferromagnetic material is great enough to overcome their repelling forces, both magnets are equally attracted to the ferromagnetic material. With both "like" poles attached to the ferromagnetic material, the center of ferromagnetic material thus becomes the opposite pole? However, once the bond between the two magnets is broken (i.e., attached to two separate pieces of ferromagnetic material), each piece simply becomes an extension of the original magnet to which it is attached, and the two units once again repel. A better explanation would be appreciated.